# Restrict access to wordpress site using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just would like to ask how can I restrict access to my WordPress site using `.htaccess` file?

I have seen sites that teaches how to protect the admin side of a WordPress site like this one:

> http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/9-most-useful-htaccess-tricks-for-wordpress/

But how about the entire site from the homepage itself?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the link that you posted and put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "WordPress Admin Access Control"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

except replacing the `AuthUserFile` with the path of the htpasswd file that you generated.

That's all.

Comment: If I already have an htaccess access file on my root directory, should I replace it with the code you posted?

Comment: @vishnu sorry, I forgot the `Require` directive. It depends on what you have in the htaccess file, you don't want to replace everything that's there, just need to add that to what you already have (assuming you don't already have those directives)

Comment: the valid-user should be replace with a username I used on the htpasswd file?